# Set RAILS_ENV for test rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've done this patch to my test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = ENV["RAILS_ENV_TEST"] || "test"
```

This works in that I can run

```
RAILS_ENV_TEST=test_dan ruby -Itest test/unit/post_test.rb
```

but I want to be able to run all kinds of test things, including `rake db:test:clone` but not using the environment `test`. How can I do this?

Comment: Nothing helping your question, but some code cleanup: `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = ENV["RAILS_ENV_TEST"] || "test"` is the same in one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most rake tasks that are namespaced with "test" will only run on your test environment and not in other environments. It's hardcoded into the task as to mitigate potentially devastating affects they might have in an environment such as production.

You can see that these tasks don't take into account the environment in which they are called in [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L446).

If you want to run these tasks in whatever environment you want, your best bet is to recreate these tasks and pass in the environment.

```
namespace :any_environment_test do
  task :load => :environment do
    ...
  task :clone => :environment do
    ...
```

In this specific case, it's a little trickier, as it sounds like you want to clone from any environment to any environment. If this is the case, you should probably have two vars that are passed, such as `FROM_ENV=` and `TO_ENV=`.

Long story longer, you're going to write custom tasks, but can inspire yourself from the link I posted above. :)

Comment: Thanks @theIV, that's great stuff. Really what's going on is that our database.yml is under source control, so the only way to have your own test DB is to use a specific rails_env...

Comment: @Yar I'm sorry but I don't follow how your database.yml being under version control is affecting your situation. Can you explain further? **Side note**: is there a reason that your database.yml file is under version control? Can you not remove it from the repository and replace it with something like database.yml.example?

Comment: thanks for asking. The way we're set up, our development, staging and production server share one codebase. This means that there's one database.yml for everyone. Therefore I either create a new config for my own specific DB connection or I make my DB fit the database.yml. No, politically I cannot remove it from the repository.

Comment: In Rails 3.1, whenever I run `rake test`, it seems to run in my current environment instead of "test".  Can you point out in the code where it should be forcing RAILS_ENV to be "test"?

Comment: @MattHuggins The file that I reference in my answer has changed a bit. I've updated the answer to point at the correct line. That being said, the question here is specific to database loading, cloning, etc. The task `test` comes from a different file: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake#L75 Still though, it should be referring to those db tasks and loading the right env, I believe. Have you messed around with your `test/test_helper.rb` file at all? In a vanilla app, the first line should be `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'`.

Comment: Hmm, that is the first line of my `test/test_helper.rb` file.  I'll have to dig in and see what's going on with my specific scenario.  Thanks!